# I need someone to tell me what is wrong with logic in my code

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java. I am trying to write code according to the following text:

> You are to write an application to pre­sell a limited number of movie
>   tickets. The simple user interface will be contained in Main.java and
>   the object to implement this is referred to as TicketSeller and
>   consists of only the following public methods:
>
> `public TicketSeller(int initialTicketAllotment)` - Specify the number
>   of tickets you want to sell.
>
> `public int requestTickets(int ticketRequest)` - Requests
>   `ticketRequest` number of tickets. Returns
>   T`icketSeller.TOO_MANY_TICKETS_REQUESTED` if there are more than
>   `TicketSeller.MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED`. Note that one of these
>   constants is private and one is public. Which one needs to be exposed
>   to the user?
>
> `public int getNumberOfBuyers()` - Tracks number of ticket buyers. You
>   only count buyers who have fulfilled a request. Errors don't count.

Here is what I have so far. However, there is an error in my code but I cannot find it:

```
public class TicketSeller {
    private final static int MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED = 4;
    public static final int TOO_MANY_TICKETS_REQUESTED = -1;
    private int buyers = 0;
    private int initialTicketAllotment;
    int placeHolder;

    public TicketSeller(int initialTicketAllotment) {
        this.initialTicketAllotment = initialTicketAllotment;

    }

    public int requestTickets(int ticketRequest) {

        if (placeHolder > 0) {
            int value = 0;
            value = placeHolder - ticketRequest;
            placeHolder = value;
            buyers += 1;
        }

        if (ticketRequest > MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED
                || ticketRequest > initialTicketAllotment) {
            return TOO_MANY_TICKETS_REQUESTED;
        }

        if (ticketRequest >= 0 && ticketRequest <= MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED
                && placeHolder == 0) {
            int value = 0;
            value = initialTicketAllotment - ticketRequest;
            placeHolder = value;
            buyers += 1;

        }

        return placeHolder;
    }

    public int getNumberOfBuyers() {
        return buyers;
    }

}
```

Incorrect output located in the code comments below:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TicketSeller ts = new TicketSeller(8);

        System.out.println(ts.requestTickets(1)); //outputs 7
        System.out.println(ts.requestTickets(2)); //outputs 5
        System.out.println(ts.requestTickets(3)); //outputs 2
        System.out.println(ts.requestTickets(1)); //outputs 1
        System.out.println(ts.requestTickets(1)); //outputs 7, instead of 0
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the error?  A compile error?  A runtime error?

Comment: Well, don't you think telling us what the error is would be helpful?

Comment: A common newbie mistake is to see an error and guess what it means or ignore it.  If you actually read the error and understand what it means it can point to the problem. If you don't know what it means you can google it or at the very least include it in your question, don't ignore the error, they are not all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logical errors lie in your constuctor and your `requestTickets(int)` method:

```
public TicketSeller(int initialTicketAllotment) {
    this.initialTicketAllotment = initialTicketAllotment;
    // you need to initialize 'placeholder' to the initial
    // amount of tickets available
    this.placeholder = initialTicketAllotment;
}

public int requestTickets(int ticketRequest) {
    // you should check if there are no more tickets to request
    // or more than MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED (4 tickets) have been
    // requested, before checking if placeholder > 0. Also, you
    // want to check if 'ticketRequest > placeholder' not the
    // initial amount of tickets.
    if (ticketRequest > MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED
            || ticketRequest > placeholder) {
        return TOO_MANY_TICKETS_REQUESTED;
    }

    // remove the local 'value' variable, it just confuses your
    // code to other readers, thinking you need a temporary variable
    // for some reason
    if (placeHolder > 0) {
        placeholder -= ticketRequest;
        buyers += 1;
    }

    // if placeholder equals 0, that means there are no more tickets
    // left... not sure why you would set it back to
    // 'initialTicketAllotment - ticketRequest'. I would get rid of this
    // method.
    /*
    if (ticketRequest >= 0 && ticketRequest <= MAXIMUM_TICKETS_ALLOWED
            && placeHolder == 0) {
        int value = 0;
        value = initialTicketAllotment - ticketRequest;
        placeHolder = value;
        buyers += 1;
    }
    */

    return placeHolder;
}
```

Comment: Got it, your code makes much more sense. Thank you for helping.